# Why are the height and width of the content View zero in Robolectric?

Tags: android-layout, robolectric, activity-lifecycle

Here's a failing test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class FailTest {

    @Test
    public void heightAndWidth_shouldNotBeZero() {
        TestActivity testActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity.class).create().resume().visible().get();
        View contentView = testActivity.findViewById(69);
        Assertions.assertThat(contentView.getWidth()).isNotZero();
        Assertions.assertThat(contentView.getHeight()).isNotZero();
    }

    private static class TestActivity extends Activity {
        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayout contentView = new LinearLayout(this);
            contentView.setId(69);
            contentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(666, 666));
            setContentView(contentView);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm calling the `visible()` method on the `ActivityController` and [driving the Activity lifecycle](http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle.html) the correct way. Quoting the documentation:

> **Wait, What's This visible() Nonsense?**
>
> Turns out that in a real Android app, the view hierarchy of an
>   `Activity` is not attached to the `Window` until sometime after `onCreate()`
>   is called. Until this happens, the Activity's views do not report as
>   visible. This means you can't click on them (amongst other unexpected
>   behavior). The Activity's hierarchy is attached to the Window on a
>   device or emulator after `onPostResume()` on the Activity. Rather than
>   make assumptions about when the visibility should be updated,
>   Robolectric puts the power in the developer's hands when writing
>   tests.
>
> So when do you call it? Whenever you're interacting with the views
>   inside the Activity. Methods like `Robolectric.clickOn()` require that
>   the view is visible and properly attached in order to function. You
>   should call `visible()` after `create()`.

It seems as though I'm doing all I need to do. So why am I getting no height/width?

Comment: Probably not related, but you're missing `start()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no layout pass in Robolectric, hence the view dimensions are always zero.

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/819